# How to show wordpress plugin content only home page?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I have create a simple WordPress plugin. For showing it on pages I have call function by using this

```
function facebook_live_counter_main_content(){
[html markups here]
add_action ('wp_head', 'facebook_live_counter_main_content');
```

It's work properly. But I want to show the plugin actions home page only. I need help by you how can I call the function for show the plugin actions home page only.

Regards-

Faysal Imran

Answer (score 5):

The correct function depends on your settings under `Admin > Settings > Reading > Front page displays`. If you have selected...

**"*A static page*"**

- Use [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) or [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) to return `true`.

**"*Your latest posts*"**

- Use [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) to return `true`.

The [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) function will return `true` if the current ***page*** is the home page, but not if your front page is a list of your latest posts. If you have selected "*Your latest posts*" under `Admin > Settings > Reading > Front page displays` you should use [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) to return `true` regardless of if the frontpage is a ***page*** or ***post listings***.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Comment: I find out it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Foysalimran consider marking as the correct answer